# Is there a way to disable pagination in kibana visualizations?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, kibana, elastic-stack

Is there a way to disable paging and just get the top 10 results in kibana. I am able to get the top 10 results but I do not want the pagination to displayed below the report.

(The reason is I am using the REQUEST from this table -- sending python queries to elastic -- parsing the response json -- and finally sending mails and for some reason the pagination is causing the results to appear in unordered nested dictionary)

[image]

Comment: When you create the visualisation you can define the visualisation size you need to set the size to 10, in addition in the option tab you can define how much record per page, maybe you can cancel the pagination there

Comment: Yes, you are partially correct .. It usually works but for some reason it chooses not to work on tables having multiple columns.